Kubernetes - Identifying incoming http requests
I'm running a kubernetes cluster with several deployments that are listening on port 3000 for http requests.
In the logs of those pods I see the following pattern, repeating every few seconds.
::ffff:192.168.137.101 - GET  /health-check 200
::ffff:192.168.21.174  - GET  / 404
::ffff:192.168.91.235  - GET  / 404

The first line is the readiness probe of the cluster itself, the IP address is of one of the cluster nodes.
The two following GET /requests are coming from an unknown source - Since the source address is 192.168.x.x I assume it's originating from within the cluster.
Running kubectl get all -o wide --all-namespaces
The output does not specify any pod or other anything else with those IP addresses.
How do I track those addresses down? What could be the source of those requests?

Use kubectl to list all pods across namespaces and examine pods with IPs matching those in the logs with kubectl get pods -o wide --all-namespaces. Additionally, inspect Kubernetes services that might be forwarding traffic to your pods using kubectl get services -A  to list all services in all namespaces, specifically focusing on services routing traffic to your pods on port 3000.

@Adedamola kubectl get pods -o wide --all-namespaces does not list any pod with those IP addresses. kubectl get services -A the services has IP address of range 10.100.0.0/16. The cluster does have an ingress (aws-load-balancer-controller) which may be the forwarding incoming traffic..

Try using the following command
kubectl get services --all-namespaces | grep <port-number>


How does get servicesprovides a solution? the IP address i see there are from 10.x.x.x subnet - not from 192.168.x.x ; why is greping the port number on the service is relevant? the deployments are listening on port 3000 they are exposed out using an ingress.

the command shows what services are using port 3000, then you can isolate those services and check your logs (e.g. graylog or other logging system )

aside from it, if you have firewall in front, you may check IP sources that are connecting to your services
